# How to get system(windows) username using javascript from the internet explorer browser?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, lan

I am developing an `asp.net` project that will be running in a lan.
Every user in this lan has its own system username.
This application will be running only on internet explorer browser.
I want to identify every client with its username.
Is there any way to do this using javascript?

Comment: You mention you are using ASP.NET. Will a solution work for you if it is in the server side code instead of Javascript? Also, what type of authentication are you using for the web site?

Comment: any reason why not use HttpContext? if its in asp.net would that be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory this should work for Internet Explorer, but could fail if the security settings on the browser are locked down.

```
var wshshell=new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell");
var username=wshshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%");
alert('hello, ' + username);
```

Also, it [isn't guaranteed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/273633) to 100% of the time match their actual AD login name.

If you are using ASP.NET you can do this much more reliably in a server-side script using `Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")` or another technique if you are using forms based authentication.

Comment: I want to identify the users without request for them their username. I use windows authentication and the Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")is working only when i browse the site from the same machine with iis. I tried the javascript commands and they are working fine when i set the ie security level to low and the activex setting to 'enable'(from 'prompt').